# call jquery plugin inner function

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, nested, call

I have one JQ plugin and I need to call nested function outside plugin.How do i call it? Here is example of the function within plugin:

```
function addTo(from, to)
{
    var dest = jQuery("#"+to)[0];

    jQuery("#"+from+" option:selected").clone().each(function() {
        if (this.disabled == true) return
        jQuery(this)
        .appendTo(dest)
        .attr("selected", false);
}
```

Comment: Don't be so lazy - write a question

Comment: You are not making it clear what exact problems you have. What happens if you try to call the function? How does the code look that doesn't work? Do you get errors?

Answer (score 1):

```
function action(elm) {
        if (!elm.disabled) { 
           jQuery(elm).appendTo(dest).attr("selected", false);
        }
}

function addTo(from, to)
{
    var dest = jQuery("#"+to)[0];

    jQuery("#"+from+" option:selected").clone().each(action(this));
}

// OUTSIDE

action(window.getElementById('id'));
```